# How to set a full screen size image as a launch screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard, launch-screen

So I need to set an image to a launch screen, it isn't just an icon with a background color, that most [docs describe how to manipulate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=windows) it.
it is a full size image like [this one](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/PcvFSTOhcmb_imJwtfpnLEk1zvFBZ7rYon-zs_0myYMrey-1Ieay0TotagageWOUuwpCc8QOekvOgQ0=w640-h1136-rw-no). I want it to look the same on every iOS device (iPhone & iPad).
But when I add new images set in assets, there are only three images to add, apparently this works perfect when using icon with a background, not a full-screen image.
I tried to add the images to the launchscreen images set but it doesn't appear under the `Image` drop-down list in the storyboard.

**EDIT**

here's how the designer looks with the constraints:

[image]

the result on iPhone X (the image is for demonstration only):

[image]

The original launch screen doesn't look fit at all, given that its size is not available among the 3 images

Comment: You just need to set the constraints properly for the `imageView` inside `LauchScreen` scene.

Comment: for your need using assests for launchscreen is better option. May be you are adding assests from your windows pc. Try to add those assests in visual studio for mac

Comment: @Kamran I've set 4 constraints: x, y, width and height to the parent's x, y, width and height respectively

Comment: Can you show that?

Comment: @Kamran Question updated with the XML file (I don't have it in the designer right now)

Comment: updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

In my case it works.
I had the task of placing the image in full screen.Do not forget to remove Safe Area in View.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The screenshot share above don't see the X and Y constraints. This is could be of the issue. The width, Height and center constraints are provided.